# JavaFX ListView Cell Layout X Slide

Tags: listview, javafx

I want a `ListView` item to slide out when the user slides across it. I have the following code to set the layout x property:

```
list.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    startX = e.getX();
});

list.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
    list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setLayoutX(startX - e.getX());
});
```

The cell stays in position. How do I get the cell to slide out of the `ListView`?

Comment: You cannot move a cell belonging to a `ListView` out side without modifying the skin, since the they are clipped at the border of the part of the listview containing the cells. So you'd need a different node for this which is impossible for the standard skin of `ListView`, since there may not be a parent you can add this node to...

Comment: @fabian Your comment got cut, what is the rest?